# Problema en el insert de una tabla intermedia

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert

les vengo a molestar con un problema
,tengo estas tres tablas

**embarque**

```
vuelo
documento
tipodocumento
```

**equipaje**

```
nroequipaje
peso
```

**equipajexpasajero**

```
nroequipaje
documento
tipodocumento
```

estoy haciendo un programa en visual basic y tengo una transaccion que primero inserta el embarque, inserta el equipaje y cuando quiero insertar el dato en la tabla intermedia se traba todo por 10 segundos y me tira error de query expired , si ejecuto el insert ese en el sql server directamente me funciona a la perfeccion tomando 0 segundos entonces no es una sobrecarga de la bd 
si ejecuto el insert fuera de la transaccion funciona perfectamente por lo que estoy completamente confundido

Comment: Podes agregar el código que hace los inserts? Antes de la transacción tenés alguna otra interacción con la BD? Tal vez algo anterior está lockeando la tabla.

Comment: Suena a que tu transacción te está bloqueando, revisa el orden en el que se realizan las operaciones